# Excel: Formulas for converting data among column / row / matrix

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, transpose

Are there formulas to convert data in a column to a matrix or to a row?
And to convert from/to other combinations?

What about an even more complex case: reshape a matrix of width W to width N*W?

There are a few similar or related questions.
I have answered some of them, marked with *.
I keep updating this list, as new similar (or equal) questions are added:

[Formatting Data: Columns to Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750687/formating-data-columns-to-rows)  *

[Move content from 1 column to 3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666516/move-content-from-1-column-to-3-columns)  *

[how to split one column into two columns base on conditions in EXCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356632/how-to-split-one-column-into-two-columns-base-on-conditions-in-excel)  *

[writing a macro to transpose 3 columns into 1 row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735590/writing-a-macro-to-transpose-3-columns-into-1-row)

[Excel VBA transpose with characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612887/excel-vba-transpose-with-characters)

[Mathematical transpose in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873014/mathematical-transpose-in-excel)

[How do transform a "matrix"-table to one line for each entry in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623972/how-do-transform-a-matrix-table-to-one-line-for-each-entry-in-excel)

[Convert columns with multiple rows of data to rows with multiple columns in Excel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613507/convert-columns-with-multiple-rows-of-data-to-rows-with-multiple-columns-in-exce)

[How to use VBA to reshape data in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497757/how-to-use-vba-to-reshape-data-in-excel)  *

[Sorting three columns into six, sorted horizontally by surname using excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522004/sorting-three-columns-into-six-sorted-horizontally-by-surname-using-excel)  *

[divide data in one column into more column in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276359/divide-data-in-one-column-into-more-column-in-excel)

[Move data from multiple columns into single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912409/move-data-from-multiple-columns-into-single-row)  *

Some of the answers appear to be "upgradeable" to something more encompassing.
Is that possible?

Sample formats to convert from/to are:

Column

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
...
```

Row

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   ...
```

Matrix (with a span of 4 columns here)

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
...
```

Comment: i think oyu can transpones the column to a row or the row to a column (with a formula `=TRANSPOSE()` or after a copy&paste); i don´t think that there is a "toMatrix" formula....you probably need to use VB or combine a lot of other formulars...

Comment: @user3116916 - Please check item 7 below. It gives a way of transposing, without using either: 1) `=TRANSPOSE()` (which requires an array formula), 2) VBA, 3) Paste special, 4) "a lot" of other formulas.

Comment: learned something new :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The idea is to give here something that can likely be used with minor adaptations to the questions listed above, which may also serve as a reference for future related questions.

The essential functions to be used are `INDEX` or `OFFSET`. The pros and cons of each one will be given after explicit examples, with reference to the figure. It shows several ranges with their defined names (in *italics* in the following).
All defined names can be replaced by direct absolute references to the corresponding cells.

[image]

**1. Column to matrix**

The *span* (in C1) gives the number of columns. Then *matrix_data_top_left* (D1 here) contains

```
=INDEX(col_data,(ROW()-ROW(matrix_data_top_left))*span+(COLUMN()-COLUMN(matrix_data_top_left)+1),1)
```

which is then copied into the rest of *matrix_data*.
Note that copying also into D5 gives an error, since the resulting formula refers to a cell outside *col_data* (A1:A16).
The same result is obtained in *matrix_data2_top_left* (I1) with

```
=OFFSET(col_data_top,(ROW()-ROW(matrix_data2_top_left))*span+(COLUMN()-COLUMN(matrix_data2_top_left)),0)
```

and copying similarly into *matrix_data2*.
Note that copying also into I5 returns `0`, not an error.

`OFFSET` has the advantage of requiring only one cell to be used as a base reference (*col_data_top*), so extending the source data range with further data does not need redefining the source data range in the formula, one has only to copy-paste into an extended target range.
On the other hand, extending the source data range using `INDEX` requires first updating it in the formula (changing the range if used explicitly), and then copy-paste into an extended target range. Using a defined name is more versatile for this purpose, as redefining *col_data* suffices here (and it can be done after extending the target range).
Due to this same property, `INDEX` provides a kind of automatic bounds checking on the source range, which `OFFSET` does not.

**2. Matrix to column**

*col_data2_top* contains

```
=INDEX(matrix_data2,INT((ROW()-ROW(col_data2_top))/span)+1,MOD(ROW()-ROW(col_data2_top),span)+1)
```

and *col_data3_top*

```
=OFFSET(matrix_data2_top_left,INT((ROW()-ROW(col_data3_top))/span),MOD(ROW()-ROW(col_data3_top),span))
```

Both formulas are copied downwards.
The same differences between `INDEX` and `OFFSET` exist.

**3. Matrix to row**

Since `OFFSET` does not give errors, the remaining formulas will use it. Adapting for `INDEX` along the lines shown above is easy.
*row_data_left* contains

```
=OFFSET(matrix_data_top_left,INT((COLUMN()-COLUMN(row_data_left))/span),MOD(COLUMN()-COLUMN(row_data_left),span))
```

then copied to the right.

**4. Column to row**

*row_data2_left* contains

```
=OFFSET(col_data_top,COLUMN()-COLUMN(row_data2_left),0)
```

again copied to the right.

PS: The formula `=TRANSPOSE(...` works for this case, and it should be entered as an array formula (with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>). Nevertheles, [it might be desirable to avoid array formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080616/2707864).

**5/6. Row to column/matrix**

It is very easy to obtain along these lines.
E.g., *col_data_top* contains

```
=OFFSET(row_data_left,0,ROW()-ROW(col_data_top))
```

and copy down.

**7. Matrix transpose**

To get in *matrix_data3* (not shown in the fig.) the transpose of *matrix_data2*, one only needs to use *matrix_data3_top_left*, with the formula

```
=OFFSET(matrix_data2_top_left,COLUMN()-COLUMN(matrix_data3_top_left),ROW()-ROW(matrix_data3_top_left))
```

and copied to a suitable target range.

**8. Matrix reshape**

We want to reshape a matrix into a wider one:
*matrix_data4*, with *N4* rows and *M4* columns (*width4*), into 
*matrix_data5*, with *N5*=*N4/R* rows and *M5*=*M4xR* columns (*width5*), with *R* (*rep5*) the number of repeats
(matrices not shown in the fig.) Then use

```
=OFFSET(matrix_data4_top_left,(ROW()-ROW(matrix_data5_top_left))*rep5+INT((COLUMN()-COLUMN(matrix_data5_top_left))/width4),MOD((COLUMN()-COLUMN(matrix_data5_top_left)),width4))
```

Now we want to reshape a matrix into a narrower one:
*matrix_data4*, with *N4* rows and *M4* columns (*width4*), into 
*matrix_data6*, with *N6*=*N4xS* rows and *M6*=*M4/S* columns (*width6*), with *S* (*split6*) the number of splits
(matrices not shown in the fig.) Then use

```
=OFFSET(matrix_data4_top_left,INT((ROW()-ROW(matrix_data6_top_left))/split6),MOD((ROW()-ROW(matrix_data6_top_left)),split6)*width4+(COLUMN()-COLUMN(matrix_data6_top_left)))
```

Comment: I know it's an old post but thank you very much for a great answer.  One comment for users, and it's not a criticism of the answer, but at the beginning when it says, "All defined names **can** be replaced by direct absolute references...".  That should be read as "**must** be replaced by direct absolute references...".  I'm sure @Sancho assumed everyone would understand that clearly, but some of us miss those details :-).  This was a great post because the TOCOL() and TOROW() functions aren't available in Excel, only Excel 365.

Comment: @Alan - No. *can* is properly used here. 
Everything can work with either defined names or absolute references.