# Move data from multiple columns into single row

Tags: excel, transpose

This formatting issue is confusing me. I'm not an Excel king and would greatly appreciate the solution to my problem.

I'm trying to format data from multiple columns into a single row by date. i.e.:

[image]

I've tried to search for solutions regarding transpose, but this seems a bit more involved. I have 4x data results for each date (as seen in the before column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple loop that works bottom up in the sheet, shifts last line over 4 columns, copies line above down and then deletes the line above.

```
Sub TransposeData()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

    Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With WS
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row
    End With

    'Loop through column A bottom up
    For i = LastCellRowNumber To 2 Step -1
        'Shift current values over
        Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

        'Copy new values down
        Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Value = Range("A" & i - 1 & ":D" & i - 1).Value

        'Delete row
        Rows(i - 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Next i
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: +1. However, it seems the code missed the time format from cells on column B in the "before" phase, at columns B, F and J in the "after" phase.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to unite the rows as from a .csv file, and then, import the new formatted information on Excel again.

1- Save your spreadsheet in comma separated value format (.csv).
2- In NotePad++, click on: Edit->Line Operations->Join Lines.
3- Replace spaces (" ") by commas(","). You should get 3 replacements.

Now you have just one line with all values separated by commas.

4- Save and import this new file on Excel.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20800820/2707864), there are several options:

1. [Item 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20800915/2707864): enter in A8


   `=OFFSET($A$2,INT((COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$8))/4),MOD(COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$8),4))`


   Copy to the right as needed.
2. You could also use `INDEX`.