# Large excel data sorting VBA help or function?

Tags: vba, excel

I have about 1000 records in an excel spreadsheet in two columns

```
Column 1:
 - Row 1- Name:
 - Row 2- Company:
 - Row 3- Tel. No:
 - Row 4- Email:
 - Row 5- Web-address:
 - Row 6- Name:
 - Row 7- Company:
 - Row 8- Tel.No:

etc

Column 2    
 - Row 1- Mike A
 - Row 2- Microsoft
 - Row 3- 78544587455
 - Row 4- mike@microsoft.com
 - Row 5- www.microsoft.com
 - Row 6- Steve B
 - Row 7- Google
 - Row 8- 1521557547
```

Now what I need is the same data but in 5 columns so its a horizontal data on vertical if that makes sense.

So the end result will look like this:

```
 Name  | Company |  Tel no.   |   Email          |   Website      | 

Mike A |Microsoft| 78544587455|mike@microsoft.com|www.microsoft.com

Steve B| Google  | 1521557547 | etc
```

Any ideas for the VBA?

Comment: Is this an ongoing repetative task? If it's just a one-off, simply select the range, and use the Edit>Copy then Edit>Paste Special>Transpose menu options

Comment: @Tim - The OP needs reshaping the data, not only transposing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20800915/2707864) is exactly what you need. Please read through the answer, especially items 1, 7 and 8.

You want to reshape column data (column B) into matrix data (depending on your choice, you may need an additional transposition).